# JMS Problems Spring Batch With Partitioned Jobs On JBoss 5.2 EAP

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch-admin

We are using Spring Batch and partitioned job extensively with our project. Occasionally we see problems with partitioned jobs getting "hung" because of what apepars to be lost messages. The remote partitions all complete but the parent step stays in STARTED. Our configuration uses 1 connection factory for reading messages from the queues (inbound gateway) and a different clustered connection to send out the partition messages (outbound gateway). The reason for this is the JBoss messaging doesnt uniformly distribute messages around the cluster and the client connection factory provides that functionality.

Redhat came in and frankly threw mud at Spring and the configuration. The following are excerpts from their report

---

The Spring JMSTemplate code employs several anti-patterns, like creating a new connection, session, producer just to send a message, then closing the connection. Also, when receiving a message it can create a consumer each time,
receive the message, then close the consumer. This can results in poor performance under load. The use of anti-patterns not only results in poor performance, but can deplete operating system resources such as
threads and file handles, since some of the connection resources are released asynchronously. Moreover, with non-durable topic subscribers you can end up losing messages, since any messages received between the closing of
the last and opening of the next consumer will be lost. There is one place where it may be acceptable to use the Spring JMSTemplate is inside the application server using the JCA managed connection factory (normally at "java:/JmsXA") and that only works when you're sending messages.
The JCA managed connection factory caches connections so they will not actually be created each time. However using the JCA managed connection factory will not resolve the issue with consumers since they are not cached.
In summary, the Spring JMSTemplate is not safe to use apart from the very specific use case of using it inside the application server with the JCA managed connection factory (java:/JmsXA) and only in that case to send messages
(do not use it to consume messages).
Using it from a JMS client application outside the application server is never safe, and using it with a standard connection factory (e.g. "ConnectionFactory," "ClusteredConnectionFactory", "jms/RemoteConnectionFactory," etc.) is
never safe; also using it to receive messages is never safe. To safely receive messages using Spring, consider the use of MessageListenerContainers [7] with MessageDriven Pojos [8].
Finally, note that issues encountered are based on JMS anti-patterns and is thus not a problem specific to JBoss EAP. For example, see a similar discussion with regard to ActiveMQ [9]. 
Red Hat does not support using the Spring JMSTemplate with JBoss Messaging apart from the one acceptable use case for sending message via JCA managed connection factory.

RECOMMENDATIONS

● As to Spring JMS, as a rule, use JCA managed connection factories configured in JBoss EAP. Do not use the Spring configured connection factories. Use JNDI template to pull in the connection factories to Spring from JBoss. This will get rid of most of the Spring JMS problems.
● Use standard JMS instead of Spring JMS for the batch job. Spring is a non-standard (and probably sub-standard implementation of JMS). Standard JMS uses a pool of a few senders to send the message and close the session after the message is sent. On the listener side, standard JMS uses a pool of works listening to a distributed Queue or Topic. Each web server has JMS listener deployed as singleton and uses standard java observer to
notify any caller that is expecting a call back.

---

The JMS connection factories are configured in JBoss and loaded via JNDI.

Can you provide your feedback on their assessment?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the overhead of creating new connections/sessions per send, you need to wrap the provider's connection factory in a `CachingConnectionFactory`. It reuses the same connection for sends and caches sessions, producers, consumers.